# VBA: Excel loop - hiding/unhiding sheets

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Hideall_butlast_10()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next ws

i = Worksheets.Count
For x = 10 To i
    Sheets(x).Select
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Next x
End Sub
```

Hey guys

I am trying to edit my code above to unhide all the sheets then hide all the sheets EXCEPT the first 5 and the last 10 (The 10 will change) - But the first 5 are always showing

My workbook has between 50-300 pages (changes daily)

Hope someone can point me in the right direction

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub Hideall_butlast_10()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws

    Const lowerBound As Integer = 5
    Const upperBound As Integer = 10

    Dim i, x
    i = Worksheets.Count
    If (i > lowerBound + upperBound) Then
        For x = lowerBound + 1 To (i - upperBound)
            Sheets(x).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Next x
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some over the top code I just wrote for ya...

```
Public Enum ToggleSheets
    Show = 1
    Hide = 2
    Toggle = 3
End Enum
Sub ToggleSheets(Optional ByVal startIndex As Integer = 1, Optional ByVal StopIndex As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal Toggle As Integer = Toggle)
    If StopIndex = 0 Then StopIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    For i = startIndex To StopIndex
        Select Case Toggle
        Case Show
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Case Hide
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Case Toggle
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Visible = 0 Then
                ToggleSheets i, i, Show
            Else
                ToggleSheets i, i, Hide
            End If
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Sample Calls:

```
ToggleSheets , , hide'hides all sheets

ToggleSheets 1,5, show 'displays first 5 sheets.
togglesheets workbooks.count - 9, , show ' shows last 10 sheets
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are only selecting the sheet, and not activating it. You need to "Activate" the sheet before using the ActiveSheet object.

Here is a modified version of your code that works:

```
Sub Hideall_butlast_10()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next ws

Dim i, x As Long

i = Worksheets.Count
For x = 1 To i - 10
    Sheets(x).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Next x
End Sub
```

Here is how I would implement it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub HideAllSheets()

Dim wkbBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim wksSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set wkbBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook

On Error Resume Next ' to suppress the error that turns up when trying to hide the last sheet
For Each wksSheet In wkbBook.Worksheets
    wksSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
Next wksSheet
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Sub UnhideAllSheets()

Dim wkbBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim wksSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set wkbBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook

On Error Resume Next
For Each wksSheet In wkbBook.Worksheets
    wksSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next wksSheet
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Sub UnhideFirstXSheets(ByVal lngX As Long)

Dim wkbBook As Excel.Workbook
Set wkbBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Dim wksSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim lngCount As Long

For lngCount = 1 To lngX
    Set wksSheet = wkbBook.Sheets(lngCount)
    wksSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next lngCount

End Sub

Sub UnhideLastXSheets(ByVal lngX As Long)

Dim wkbBook As Excel.Workbook
Set wkbBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Dim wksSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim lngCount As Long
Dim lngSheetCount As Long
lngSheetCount = wkbBook.Worksheets.Count

For lngCount = 1 To lngX
    Set wksSheet = wkbBook.Sheets(lngSheetCount - lngCount + 1)
    wksSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Next lngCount

End Sub

Sub DoWhatYouWant()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Call UnhideAllSheets 'Unhide all the sheets (not really necessary
Call HideAllSheets 'Hide everything. Leaves the last sheet visible, because all the sheets in a workbook cannot be hidden
Call UnhideFirstXSheets(5) 'Unhides the first X sheets
Call UnhideLastXSheets(10) 'Unhides the last X sheets
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Run the 'DoWhatYouWant' macro and that should do. Feel free the change the 5 and 10 as per your requirement.

Comment: UnhideFirstXSheets fails (Err.#9) if number of sheets is < 5 and UnhideLastXSheets fails if number of sheets is < 10.

Comment: Yes, selecting a sheet makes it the active sheet.  Activate is normally used when you have more than 1 sheet selected. Eg, Sheet(x).Activate makes Sheet(x) the active sheet while still keeping your other sheets selected. But normally Sheets(x).Select is used to make Sheet(x) the active sheet.

Comment: Daniel, Do you mean to say it fails when you call it with a number less than 5. I do not understand the problem. Could you give more information please?